# How can I debug my docker container with docker-machine and PHPStorm

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug, boot2docker, docker-machine

I'm trying to use **Xdebug** with **docker** and **docker-machine**.

Here my **xdebug.ini** config file:

```
zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/php5-xdebug.log
```

Here my docker-compose.yml file:

```
data:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
    - ./:/srv

web:
  build: docker/nginx
  volumes_from: [data]
  links:
    - fpm
  ports:
    - "80:80"

fpm:
  build: docker/php-fpm
  volumes_from: [data]
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
```

I have configured PHPStorm like this:

[image: phpstorm config 1]
[image: phpstorm config 2]

When I try to debug a page. This window appear:

[image: phpstorm issue]

If I click ok for this window, then xdebug seem to work.

If I look at the Debugger pan I can see I'm on my root page. (app.php).
But PHPStorm don't highlight the current line.

[image: current line not highlight]

Is my configuration correct ?

Am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Comment: If this is still relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689554/xdebug-with-phpstorm-and-a-docker-container -- should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally manage to resolve this issue.

Once you have create the server, here it's **Docker**

[image]

You have to create a **Run/Debug configuration**. Add a new **PHP Remote Debug** with the **configured server** and **ide key** Then click on the debug button [image] and it's work !

[image]

For information, the Run/Debug configuration :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin, does the IP address 192.168.99.100 belong to your Mac itself or the Docker Machine/boot2docker VM? Since PHPStorm is running on your Mac, xdebug needs to connect to it on port 9000, so php.ini needs to have your Mac IP address, not the VM IP. That hung me up for a bit, hopefully this will help you too.

Comment: I'll check this next week. Thank for the infos.

Comment: Hi, setting the IP change nothing, any idea ?

Comment: You don't have to set the IP if you use `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`