# Xdebug with PHPStorm and a Docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, boot2docker

Setup: Windows 10; Docker running with Boot2Docker on Hyper-V; PHPStorm 9

Webserver on the VM is Nginx. I've configured the xdebug.ini for php5-fpm as:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

If I set a breakpoint and reload the page I get an incoming connection from Xdebug in PHPStorm:

[image: Incoming connection]

I wonder that there is only one file shown and not the entire project which is much bigger. If I accept the connection I can debug the very first line but it is not stopping on my breakpoint and creates a server entry which looks like:

[image: Server]
**What is very strange that host is empty.**
I already added the server with the correct mapping but it got ignored.

So how to get Xdebug to stop on breakpoints?

Comment: *"What is very strange that host is empty."* That's nginx misconfiguration -- you need to configure servername variable/parameter there (in nginx config file)

Comment: *"I wonder that there is only one file shown and not the entire project which is much bigger."* The script currently executed is `index.php` and this dialog is asking for path mappings (so that IDE can know what LOCAL file corresponds to that remote). Why do you need to see ALL OTHER files in this dialog? You want to be even more confused trying to find the right file in a huge list?

Comment: *"and creates a server entry which looks like:"* I suggest to move mappings 1 level higher -- map root folder (`C:\Dev\www\projectname`) to your `/var/wwww/projectname` -- right now only website root is mapped.

Comment: *"I can debug the very first line but it is not stopping on my breakpoint"* Where those breakpoints are set, what files, what kind of lines? If it's in a file that is not mapped -- see above. If file is already mapped -- make sure that breakpoints are on simple lines (e.g. whole instruction is on single line).

Comment: _"What is very strange that host is empty."_ The missing servername was the issue. Added `servername _;` and everything works. Somehow PHPStorm cannot handle empty server names.
_"and creates a server entry which looks like:"_ I missed to mention that I did that. The image was the mapping created by default from PHPStorm.

@LazyOne Can you answer the question to make it more obvious for others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is very strange that host is empty.

PhpStorm requires this field to be filled as it uses this to recognize what server entry (and therefore path mappings) to use -- IDE supports debugging the same code base running on different domains / remote servers.

In this particular case the `servername` field / parameter of your nginx configuration is empty. You can fix this by providing some value in nginx config file.

Comment: Thanks for this comment! Defining a servername made Xdebug works and also using my breakpoints.

Comment: At these days you can just put into php container this env variable `PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=your_host` and match `your_host` with server configuration *Name* (NOT with the Host) at PHP->Server settings page of PHPStorm.