# PhpStorm mapping paths

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, docker, phpstorm

I'm setup a docker container with SSH and FTP access.

My local project looks like this:

`/Users/gezimhome/projects/ziprecipes.net/zip-recipes` is my project dir. The source code for my WordPress plugin is in `src` folder.
I have wordpress downloaded and extracted locally here in `/Users/gezimhome/projects/ziprecipes.net/workdir/wordpress`.

Here are my deployment settings:
[image]

My mappings:
[image]

My server:
[image]

In the docker container, wordpress is downloaded and uncompressed here: 
`/usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress/` and I map `/Users/gezimhome/projects/ziprecipes.net/zip-recipes/src` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/zip-recipes` when creating the container.

Xdebug is setup properly because I get this `Incoming Connection from Xdebug` screen:
[image]

So, question is, since I already have the mapping why does it keep bothering me to do a mapping for wordpress files?!

And the bigger question is, why are my breakpoints in my plugin not being hit at all?!

Please help :(

Comment: **1)** Your `Server name` field on last screenshot is empty. Is it really like that? Or you just edited it out? It should be filled with some info. If it's empty then you have to fix your web server config inside your Docker as PhpStorm uses that field to identify the server/mappings (I assume you are using nginx as web server -- looks familiar) **2)** The "Server name" field must match the value from your "Host" field from your 2nd screenshot.

Comment: As a reference (most likely will be your case here as well) -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/32691518/783119

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much, @LazyOne. I almost didn't post that last screenshot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up a `Server` the `Host` needs to match server host name. For my case I set server host to `zrdn`:
[image]

The web server needs to have the server name configured as well. In my case, I configured `nginx` like so:

```
server {
        listen   8080;
        server_name zrdn;
        ...
```

Thanks a million, @LazyOne!

Comment: I was facing the same problem. Adding the server_name to nginx.conf solved it!